# Optional Parameter in GET Requests for ASP.NET Core API not Working with Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, openapi

I'm working on an endpoint which looks like this:

```
GET {{url}}/v1.0/GroupsInfo/StuffToGet/1/2/hea
```

where the 2 integers are certain ids and the text on the end is a search term.

I want the last parameter (the search text) to be optional. I have got that working using the following, but it does not appear as mandatory in Swagger:

```
[Route("[action]/{catId:int}/{dogId:int}/{search?}")]
public IActionResult StuffToGet(int catId, int dogId, string search)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Swagger is ignoring the question mark on the end of the Search parameter in the route constraint.

Is this a known issue, or do I need to right some custom code to get Swagger to recognise that optional flag?

Comment: It will be working. Do you have any problem?

Comment: @Serge Sorry. I need to re-phrase my question. You are correct. It does work. However, it does not work with Swagger. Swagger makes it a mandatory parameter. Will edit question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variant will be working, but if you have a problem with swagger try this

```
[Route("[action]/{catId:int}/{dogId:int}]
[Route("[action]/{catId:int}/{dogId:int}/{search}")]
public IActionResult StuffToGet(int catId, int dogId, string search)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

or maybe this

```
[Route("StuffToGet/{catId:int}/{dogId:int}/{search}")]
public IActionResult StuffToGet(int catId, int dogId, string search)
{
    // do stuff
}
[Route("StaffToGet/{catId:int}/{dogId:int}]
public IActionResult StuffToGet(int catId, int dogId)
{
   return StuffToGet(catId, dogId,string.empty);
}
```

Comment: I did try that. It added a second textbox for the search variable in the Swagger interface, but it kept the mandatory textbox for the search variable as well.

Comment: Sorry, I got that wrong, it created a whole new endpoint, but the "try it out" section still contained the mandatory search parameter textbox, even though it was not in the actual url signature for that endpoint.

Comment: Yeah. That's it. A pity you have to create a whole new endpoint. But it works.

Comment: Yes, sometimes swagger makes strange stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Create two actions with similar routes, but one without the search parameter. Both actions call the same business layer code.